# Apache2 Ubuntu libphp5.so not found

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server

I used the following link to build php 5.2 from source. I don't need any other version hence I didn't install the latest version.

http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204

I used *checkinstall* in place of *make install*.
And after that, the following happens

```
$service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2   [FAIL]                                                                                                
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Tried *find & locate* to search for the libphp5.so but no luck. It simply doesn't exist.

```
#apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 10 2015 13:05:59
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

So can someone please suggest a solution?

Please note: I need PHP5.2 for drupal 6 and don't have an option to use something else.
apt-get installs php 5.5.9 for all relevant commands such as libapache2-mod-php5.
Hence ruins the stand to let me keep 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading from Internet & copying the said file to associated location did the trick